# angular-datatables `Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, datatables

Please help. I can't get my server-side [datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing) working.

When I add the `.withOption('ajax', ...)` to the options, it can't load anymore. I get the error: `Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`

This is my HTML:

```
<table id="myTable" datatable class="table table-striped" dt-options="options" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th><!--Col3--></th>
        <th><!--Col4--></th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
        <th>Col7</th>
        <th>Col8</th>
        <th>Col9</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This is my JS in my controller:

```
$scope.options = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    url: '/api/all',
                    processing: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataSrc: 'data'
                })
                .withOption('processing', true)
                .withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withBootstrap()
                .withLanguageSource('lib/datatables/lang/Dutch.json')
                .withOption('searching', false);
```

EDIT - Also important to know that there has not been a AJAX call for the data.

Can somebody tell me what is going on??

Comment: you have  `dataSrc: 'data'` with data between quotes ... Have you tried that?  `dataSrc: data`

Comment: That's not going to work because data wouldn't be defined.

Comment: Obvious... then what´s the data you need to pass? a string with the word "data" ?? ....  Then just don´t pass it... read your own text saying `When I add the .withOption('ajax', data)` without quotes....

Comment: Excuse me for the error. `data` in the first sentence is a 'placeholder'. Please refer to the code only. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ok it's clear now, `processing: true` should NOT be in the ajax options.. Sorry.